# How to run a scheduled Function in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

I am not sure how to go about this in Java, For fun, Assume I am building a bank model, and I would like to calculate the total interest accumulated for a customer when his account matures. I can check if an account is mature or not and then do the math, but is there a way to have this done automatically, I assume a real bank software would do this automatically, or this a database trigger?

Comment: I could, For whatever reason I am thinking there is a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: What sort of elegance were you looking for? Champagne? Or a scheduled executor service perhaps?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you wouldn't want to take software advice from a real bank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want elegance for your hypothetical bank; then you can use a thread whose main job is to `calculate the total interest accumulated for a customer when his account matures.`

Your bank software will be doing other things, adding new accounts, transferring money, but the thread will always be there checking.

Now the thread would not run for ever, it could wake up everyday at midnight and start its search/task. Or it could wake up a couple of key times during the day and do a portion of the task. You can wake it up using a timer and a `synchronized` block.

```
synchronized(timeObj) 
{
    // Check all bank accounts for "maturity" and interests.
}
```

This is of course an abstraction of what you will built, once you get started you can tweak it to your liking.